# Reading accounting information with regex

Tags: python, regex

**Context**

In my daily job I lost a lot of time putting values in excel from a balance sheet manually, so I start learning how to code in python to speed up my work.

**Problem**

I am trying to create a regex that is able to detect the value of one account and send me the money that the account haves. The issue is there are multiple software's and the regex gets very complex because of that.

**Examples of different outputs from accounting software's**

As you see there is always a pattern: One Account Name that is a string that can have multiple spaces and special characters;
One column of values of credit and debt with a comma and ,

The account number can have commas or not in it

**Example 1**

| Random number | Account number | Account Name | credit$ | Debt$ | Value of account |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 53 | Another Financial Instruments | 1.100,00 | 1.500,00 | 400,00 D |
|  | 531 | Café C/C (Taxes) | 100,00 | 50,00 | 50,00 C |
| 230 | 5321 | Example | 100,00 | 50,00 | 50,00 C |
|  | 54 | Example 2 | 300,00 | 500,00 | 200,00 D |

This the most complex output because they put a random number behind the account number so there is accounts with a double space between the random number and number of account and other do not have any space

10 __ 53 -> with space
54 -> no space because of no random number
Also the column value of the account that is equals to Credit - Debt if credit > Debt they had a C into the value, else they had a D

**Example 2**

| Account number | Account Name | credit$ | Debt$ | Value of account |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.3 | Another Financial Instruments | 1.100,00 | 1.500,00 | 400,00 |
| 5.3.1 | Café C/C (Taxes) | 100,00 | 50,00 | 50,00 |
| 5.3.2.1 | Example | 100,00 | 50,00 | 50,00 |
| 5.4 | Example 2 | 300,00 | 500,00 | 200,00 |

In this example there is no random number or D or C in the value of the account, but there is a comma in the account number.

**Example 3**

| Account number | Account Name | credit$ | Debt$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 53 | Another Financial Instruments | 1.100,00 | 1.500,00 |
| 531 | Café C/C (Taxes) | 100,00 | 50,00 |
| 5321 | Example | 100,00 | 50,00 |
| 54 | Example 2 | 300,00 | 500,00 |

This is the easiest one, no comma in account numbers no random number, but there is no Account value column so the accountant always need to insert both debt and credit values and calculate the difference.

My newbie regex only for the 1st example `(\d{2,4}\s) (\w+(\s+\w+)+(\s+\w+)*) (\s\d,\d\d\s)` it's not working for all the values.

The end goal is to export the output of python to excel and do a PROCV of the account number and the value to do some analysis.

I have tried to convert the pdf to excel or to word but it gets broken.

**Updade:**

**Example 1 real life example:**

In my examples above I didnt mention that there are 3 more columns debt and credit of the month and the difference between them than you have the debt and credit of the year and the final value. I didnt mention to simplify the examples.

The real life are on portuguese the names sry for that.

12  DEPÓSITOS À ORDEM  55.884,44  42.165,87  750.656,46  427.920,52  322.735,94 D

2  121  Banco BPI, Sa  55.884,44  42.152,35  750.503,75  427.792,60  322.711,15 D

2  122  Novo Banco s a  0,00  13,52  152,71  127,92  24,79 D

13  OUTROS DEPÓSITOS BANCÁRIOS  0,00  0,00  87.277,22  0,00  87.277,22 D

131  DEPOSITOS A PRAZO  0,00  0,00  87.277,22  0,00  87.277,22 D

**Example 3**

The example 3 only haves debt and credit of the month and debt and credit of the year

12 Depósitos à ordem 4.237.864,32 3.524.858,99 713.005,33 0,00

13 Outros depósitos bancários 400.000,00 0,00 400.000,00 0,00

14 Outros Instrumentos financeiros 49.992,28 0,00 49.992,28 0,00

33 Matérias-primas, subsidiárias e de consumo 1.721.079,97 843.549,38
877.530,59 0,00

--
Ty for the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example data, you might use an approach with capture groups and for the `Value of account` create an optional group at the end of the pattern.

If you have more columns, you can extend the pattern.

When using code, you can check for the existence of the last optional group.

```
^(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\s+(.+?)\s+(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2})\s+(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2})(?:\s+(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}(?:\s+[CD])?))?$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits and optionally repeat matching a dot and 1+ digits for *Account number*
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(.+?)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ chars, as least as possible for *Account name*
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2})` Capture **group 3**, the money format for *credit$*
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2})` Capture **group 4**, the money format for *Debt$*
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
  - `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}(?:\s+[CD])?)`  capture **group 5**, the money format for *Value of account* with an optional part matching 1+ whitespace chars and either C or D
- `)?` Close non caputure group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/FmY6Hc/1).

Comment: Ty for the explanation! But for the Example 1 I gave your Regex is getting the random number "10" and "230" and putting in the group 2 the account number with the name of the account. I added the real Life outputs if you prefer to test on it!

Comment: @TiagoCoelho If you omit the anchor `$` then the `.+?` would not over match. See https://regex101.com/r/jFNYja/1

Comment: 2 121 Banco BPI, Sa 55.884,44 42.152,35 750.503,75 427.792,60 322.711,15 D

I am very grateful for your help! But in the real life example one there is a number 2 behind the number 121, the 2 is the random number that I dont care and the 121 is the number of the account. Your regex is putting the random number on the group 1 with the rest of the number accounts and is putting number account in the group 2.

Comment: @TiagoCoelho If for example the Account name can not start with a digit, you can make the first random number optional and make sure that the Account name starts with a non whitespace char except for a digit. See https://regex101.com/r/vQhZob/1